# What is this strange almost symmetrical location in Nevada?

Tags: where-on-earth, identify-this, nevada

We were looking at this and trying to establish what it is and if it's something interesting to travel to.  However it looks like some crop circle-style icons south east of it, and evidence of military nearby.

Can anyone [identify what it is](https://www.google.com.au/maps/@39.8780684,-118.3983103,456m/data=!3m1!1e3)? Also seems to be tanks south of the structures?

Bing has [higher resolution](https://binged.it/2dEOY1i):

[image: weird structure]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47169/discussion-between-fiksdal-and-lightness-races-in-orbit) @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Putting a screenshot of Bing Maps [through reverse image search](http://tineye.com/search/fcd916c5c0697d7e264021a046c017c06cd78648/) gives a second source (in addition to the forum) which includes some additional information.

From [The Most Stunning Satelite Photos](http://www.rumblerum.com/satellite-photos-2015/) by the technology publication [RumbleRum](http://www.rumblerum.com/about/).

> **Fallon Range Training Complex, Dixie Valley, Nevada, USA**
>
> The Fallon Range Training Complex is a United States Navy military
>   area spanning across 84,000 acres in the Dixie Valley of Nevada, USA.
>   The complex primarily hosts air-to-air and air-to-ground training
>   exercises. In the picture given below, you can see an installation of
>   metal containers that are used for covert operations training as well
>   as instrument recognition and calibration for spy planes and
>   satellites.

You can read more about this complex on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallon_Range_Training_Complex). That article also provides sources for the fact that this complex is in a [restricted area](http://www.militaryfactory.com/dictionary/military-terms-defined.asp?term_id=4596). Therefore, even if someone would *want* to travel there, it would be illegal, very dangerous, and probably very difficult to attempt that.

Comment: Illegal, dangerous, difficult, and… *stupid*.

Comment: +1, also light aircraft are restricted.

Comment: If you'd move some of those containers, they would think all those satellites have a defect.

Comment: @Agent_L Great idea!! I'll try that on my next holiday and post a trip report as a Q&A here! I hope it won't be closed as off-topic... Now, considering they are actually shipping containers, how do I move them...? Hmmm... I think I'll need some sort of truck. Challenge accepted.

Comment: It seems strange they describe it as **Stunning!**  It's literally nothing more than a paint-ball field.  So what?

Comment: @JoeBlow: Just standard lazy clickbait wording...

Comment: tl;dr: it's your tax dollars at work =P

Comment: @JoeBlow probably because most of human beings on this planet do not have 84,000 acres of garden, and even more the few million dollars needed to fill them with containers and fake buildings just to play paintball?

Comment: I don't think it's especially hard to travel there, but you will have to *enlist*.

Answer (score 20):

From the discussion [here](https://www.metabunk.org/odd-structures-in-google-maps-in-nevada.t5537/), it seems that the structures are used for military "urban warfare" training and may be constructed from shipping containers.

Probably not the best place to visit while on vacation.

Comment: +1, I remember being told it was a military training ground. I had the impression it was for urban ground fighting, but targets will do nicely. Interesting discussion link also, thanks

Comment: Several comments in the linked thread do state that it's for urban warfare training rather than target practice -- which in my eye does look like the better explanation. The symmetric layout would mean you can pit two teams of trainees against each other and not need to figure out if one of them has a natural advantage of terrain you need to correct for when scoring.

Comment: Dutch version: https://www.google.nl/maps/@53.3860852,6.2627522,853m/data=!3m1!1e3?hl=en

Comment: AFAIK -> nato training grounds for the yearly nato ground operations. there's similar ones in zgza.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich haha, "oefendorp" ... Exercise/practice town.

Comment: @HenningMakholm True. Answer edited.