# What are these things in the desert near Fallon, Nevada?

Tags: usa, identify-this, deserts, nevada

I was playing with **Google Earth** and was looking for ***Fallon Range Training Complex*** after I read [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81129/what-is-this-strange-almost-symmetrical-location-in-nevada/81139#81139). So I typed *"Fallon"* and I dragged the cursor all along and spotted some really curious things.

Well, it was a number of circles that dangerously resembled radars. One of them had a click next to it and it said "Battle Mountain, NV, USA". I Googled that and learned that it was a gold-mining center in Nevada that is no longer a municipality. But that doesn't answer what these huge circles are.

[image]

Any guesses what this is?

Comment: "dangerously resembled radars" - old-school radar *displays* perhaps, but not the radars themselves...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It is a specific form of irrigation know as [Center Pivot Irrigation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_pivot_irrigation)

Fairly simply explained on Wikipedia

> Center-pivot irrigation (sometimes called central pivot irrigation), also called waterwheel and circle irrigation, is a method of crop irrigation in which equipment rotates around a pivot and crops are watered with sprinklers.  A circular area centered on the pivot is irrigated, often creating a circular pattern in crops when viewed from above (sometimes referred to as crop circles). Most center pivots were initially water-powered, and today most are propelled by electric motors.

No crazy alien landings here!

Comment: [Simpsons fans know](https://frinkiac.com/meme/S04E04/239071/m/IFNlZSBUSEUgQ0lSQ1VMQVIgUEFUVEVSTgogT04gVEhPU0UgRklFTERTPyBUSEFUJ1MKIEZST00gQ0VOVFJBTCBQSVZPVAogSVJSSUdBVElPTi4=).

Comment: They also seem to be used quite a bit in less arid climates... I have seen a lot of them on flights over the grain belt states.

Comment: @Michael Indeed. I've seen many of these when flying over many different parts of the U.S. They're quite common.

Comment: @Michael - Yeah I fly a lot for work, it sparked my interest a long time ago seeing all these funny circles everywhere.

Comment: These are really common in the agricultural regions of southern Delaware. Many can be seen from the roads.